# Advanced Custom Fields Repeater With 2 Loops

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am setting up a photo gallery, with a main image and 6 thumbnails under it. Upon hovering the thumbnail, the main image will change. Simple stuff. The problem I am having is that when the page loads, the main image is the image from the first repeater row (like I want), but then in the thumbnails, the first repeater row doesn't get output. So only thumbnails 2 - 6 are being output. I am new to Advanced Custom Fields. Not sure if it's something to do with that or if it's just a simple PHP error. Here is my code:

```
<?php if( have_rows('property_images') ): 

    while( have_rows('property_images') ): the_row();

        $image = get_sub_field('property_image');
        $url = $image['url'];

    ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $url ?>" class="property-main-img">

    <?php
        break;
        endwhile;
        endif; 
    ?>

            <ul>

                <?php if( have_rows('property_images') ): 

                        $i = 1;

                        while( have_rows('property_images') ): the_row();

                            $image = get_sub_field('property_image');
                            $url = $image['url'];

                        ?>

                        <?php if($i % 3 == 0) { ?>

                            <li class="prop-thumb-r"><img src="<?php echo $url ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" width="170" /></li>

                        <?php } else if($i == 1 || $i % 4 == 0) { ?>

                            <li class="prop-thumb-l"><img src="<?php echo $url ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" width="170" /></li>

                        <?php } else { ?>

                            <li><img src="<?php echo $url ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" width="170" /></li>

                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php
                             $i++;
                         endwhile; 
                    endif; 
                ?>

            </ul>
```

Comment: Not too clear why this wouldn't work, are you able to link to an example? For testing, have you tried putting the second loop before the first, this would rule out if the first loop or the 'break' is somehow affecting your second loop.

Comment: @johnnyd23 I just tried swapping the while loops and it did work how I want. Obviously, things aren't in the order I want them now though. But all the content I want to be displayed is displaying. I tried changing my variable names to make sure they weren't conflicting and that didn't work. I also put everything in one while loop and that didn't fix it either. Kinda stumped at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the break might be causing the problem. Try using this method to get the first image by grabbing only the first row from the repeater field.

```
<?php 
    $rows = get_field( 'property_images' );
    $first_image = $rows[0]['property_image'];
?>

<img src="<?php echo $first_image['url'] ?>" class="property-main-img">
```